# Would Sklearn GridSearchCV go through all the possible default options of the estimator's parameters?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-analysis, knn, grid-search

Algorithms in scikit-learn might have some parameters that have default range of options,

```
sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, weights='uniform', algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, p=2, metric='minkowski', metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, **kwargs)
```

and the parameter has a default value "auto", with the following options: **`algorithm`** : {‘auto’, ‘ball_tree’, ‘kd_tree’, ‘brute’}

My question is, when using `**GridSearchCV**` to find the best set of values for the parameters of an algorithm, would GridSearchCV go though all the default options of a parameter even though I don't add it to the parameter_list?

For example, I want to use `**GridSearchCV**` to find the best parameter values for `**kNN**`, I need to examine the `n_neighbors` and `algorithm` parameters, is it possible that I just need to pass the values with no as below (because the `algorithm` parameter has default options),

```
parameter_list = {'n_neighbors': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]}
```

or, I have to specify all the options that I want to examine?

```
parameter_list = {
'algorithm': ['auto', 'ball_tree', 'kd_tree', 'brute'],
'n_neighbors': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You are misunderstanding about the parameter default and available option.

Looking at the [documentation of `KNeighborsClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html), the parameter `algorithm` is an optional parameter (i.e. you may and may not specify it during constructor of KneighborsClassifier).

But if you decide to specify it, then it has options available: `{‘auto’, ‘ball_tree’, ‘kd_tree’, ‘brute’}`. It means that you can give the value only from these given options for `algorithm` and cannot use any other string to specify for `algorithm`. The default option is `'auto'`, means that if you dont supply any value, then it will internally use `'auto'`.

- **Case 1**:- `KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)`

Here since no value for `algorithm` has been specified, so it will by default use algorithm='auto'.

- **Case 2**:- `KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, algorithm='kd_tree')`

Here as the algorithm has been specified, so it will use 'kd_tree'

Now, `GridSearchCV` will only pass those parameters to the estimator which are specified in the `param_grid`. So in your case when you use the first `parameter_list` from the question, then it will give only `n_neighbors` to the estimator and algorithm will have only default value (`'auto'`).

If you use the second `parameter_list`, then both `n_neighbors` and `algorithm` will be passed on to the estimator.